# Delphi Firemonkey how to audio & video live streaming

Tags: delphi, video-streaming, firemonkey, audio-streaming

How can I live streaming Audio & Video with Delphi Firemonkey? My Streaming will be client to client. Have tried with Indy TCP, UDP & HTTP. All are very slow in lower bandwidth. I used TAudioCaptureDevice & TVideoCaptureDevice for audio and video and send them to server and client get as stream for TCP/UDP and row file with HTTP. All of my transactions are using TIdSync under

```
TThread.Queue(TThread.Current, 
  procedure
  begin
    //call to TIdSync for processing the data
  end
);
```

What is the best technique to achieve faster transaction?

Comment: UDP for streaming.  Why are you using `Queue` if you're also using `TIdSync`?  If your code is slow, you'll need to profile it.  When you find the bottleneck, show us your code.

Comment: As usual that wheel has been invented already. http://www.fmxexpress.com/video-streaming-using-motion-jpeg-with-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-on-windows-and-ios/   (unfortunatly that code uses `synchonize`, but you can easily tweak it to use `TThread.Queue` instead). (The source is here: http://www.fmxexpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/MJPEGDecoderXE4.zip )